# Asynchronous requests rails apache/phusionpassenger

Tags: apache, asynchronous, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger, thin

I've implemented a controller method which makes a couple of requests to an third parry API, which is quite slow. Further I've utilized one of [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)'s asynchronous features:

```
# This informs thin that the request will be handled asynchronously
self.response_body = ''
self.status = -1
Thread.new do
  # This will be the response to the client
  env['async.callback'].call('200', {}, "Response body")
end
```

[(blog post about it)](http://www.jonb.org/2013/01/25/async-rails.html)

However I'm curious if this could be implemented without using Thin, or to be more precise if that could be accomplished with Apache/Phusionpassenger.

Any suggestions, pointers, links, comments or answers are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure wether this is possible now with passenger 4. In [this article](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/10/24/phusion-passenger-4-0-beta-1-is-here/) They announced having made a complete
redesign to support the evented model. As they also do have plans to support Node.js, I would expect the above method to work.

However if you look at [this post](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/08/03/why-rails-4-live-streaming-is-a-big-deal/) from them, they clearly say:

> ... There is another way to support high I/O concurrency though: multi-threading ...
>
> And so this leaves multithreaded servers as the only serious options for handling streaming support in Rails apps....

Rails is just not designed for the evented process model, but it supports the multi-threaded model quite well. And multithreaded sutup can be achieved with passenger-enterprise.

Another option might be to extract this problem to another application (see [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)).
So for example instead of directly calling a 3d party api in you controller, which will spend the most time on blocking the I/O call, you solve this by processing this request in a backround job. The user will get an immidiate reponse and after that directly subscribe on some faye message channel. In your background job, when the 3d party call is ready, you publish the response on this channel to faye.
PROFIT.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, seems like a reasonable solution. However a bit overkill if you'd just want a couple of async request.

Comment: The second option would be indeed an otherkill. It would be great to see some puma/passenger-enterprise multithreaded deployments out there. You could then totally do the blocking io calls and you app server would just suspend the thread until io is ready to process without blocking a complete rails process. 

Rails actually claims to be threadsafe, but because Ruby has not had a concurrency focus for basically its entire life, nobody has been thinking about writing thread-safe code in the gem ecosystem.
So the second solution is actually a serious option.

Comment: I've ended up using Puma and running rails in a multithreaded env. with great success, although for other apps I've built (didn't bother to convert the existing one)